# Why copyto with ROI yields blank result?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have image defined like so:

```
cv::Mat mapCanva = cv::Mat(256, 256, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar::all(0));
```

and other

```
cv::Mat shapeToBlit is loaded from png file, its 100x100

shapeToBlit .copyTo(mapCanva );
```

works fine, but resulting image is 100x100, while I expect shapeToBlit to be copied on top of mapCanvas, so I do:

```
cv::Mat insetImage = mapCanva(cv::Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));
shapeToBlit .copyTo(insetImage);
```

but result is just blank, like nothing is copied. Hmmmmmm.

if I do:

```
shapeToBlit .copyTo(mapCanva(cv::Rect(100, 100, ourWidth, ourHeight)));
```

my applicatoin simply crashes inside matrix.cpp on line:

```
CV_Assert(!fixedSize() || ((Mat*)obj)->size.operator()() == Size(cols, rows));
```

What am I doing wrong? Tried both on version 2.4 and 3.4

Comment: I am having problems understanding your question. Is your output image supposed to be of the size 100x100, 256x256 or even 356x356? Is shapeToBlit supposed to be the the first part in mapCanva? This is btw no minimal, complete and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: probably the `mapCanva` should be of type `CV_8UC3`

Comment: I bet it's a mismatch between number of channels, as Miki alludes. That would cause `copyTo` to reallocate the ROI, the temporary being promptly discarded and `mapCanva` being left unmodified.